# How can I make a profile-specific bootstrap.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I want to have different property values in a `bootstrap.yml` file depending on a spring profile  passed to a starting application (the same way as it works for `application-{profile-name}.yml`).

How is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation it should work pretty much the same.

**[Changing the Location of Bootstrap Properties](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#customizing-bootstrap-properties)**:

> If there is an active profile (from `spring.profiles.active` or through the `Environment` API in the context you are building), properties in that profile get loaded as well, the same as in a regular Spring Boot app — for example, from `bootstrap-development.properties` for a `development` profile.

That is it should be possible to suffix the bootstrap yaml with the environment name to make it take effect.